# Apache 1.3 Rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rule in .htaccess which works on apache 2.4.X but not with apache 1.3, please let me know how do I make it work with apache 1.3.42

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#HTML
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)[B-Z]{3}(.*)\D{1}\.gif$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gif$ /AdDeveloper_SaDnOJ2.php?file=$1.html [NC,L]


#IMAGE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)[B-Z]{3}(.*)\d{1}\.gif$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gif$ /AdDeveloper_SaDnOJ2.php?file=$1.gif [NC,L]

#JAVASCRIPT
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} SaDnOJ2\.js$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js$ /AdDeveloper_SaDnOJ2.php?file=script.js [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can't you simply update the version? Apache 1.3.42 dates back to 2010 which is **ages** in information technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache 1. uses *POSIX Extended Regular Expressions* and those don’t understand shorthand character classes like `\d`. So try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#HTML
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)[B-Z]{3}(.*)[^0-9]{1}\.gif$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gif$ /AdDeveloper_SaDnOJ2.php?file=$1.html [NC,L]


#IMAGE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)[B-Z]{3}(.*)[0-9]{1}\.gif$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.gif$ /AdDeveloper_SaDnOJ2.php?file=$1.gif [NC,L]

#JAVASCRIPT
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} SaDnOJ2\.js$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js$ /AdDeveloper_SaDnOJ2.php?file=script.js [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working!

Comment: Please remove these useless `{1}`.